# Get allDirectories() in Laravel and create a tree

Tags: php, laravel

I'm totally stuck with this.
I have this array:

```
array:20 [▼
  0 => "test"
  1 => "files"
  2 => "files/2"
  3 => "files/2/Blocks"
  4 => "files/2/Blocks/thumbs"
  5 => "files/shares"

]
```

And I need to have an array like a tree, attaching files/2 as a child of files, and files/2/block as a child of files/2.

The array that I need is like:

```
[
            ["label" => "test", "path" => "test", "children" => []],
            ["label" => "files", "path" => "1", "children" =>
                [
                    ["label" => "2", "path" => "files/2", "children" =>
                        [
                            ["label" => "Blocks", "path" => "files/2/Blocks", "children" =>
                                [
                                    [
                                        "label" => "thumbs", "path" => "files/2/Blocks/thumbs", "children" => []
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    ["label" => "shares", "path" => "files/shares", "children" => []]
                ]
            ],
        ];
```

Is there any magic help? I really can't find the way to create that tree.

Comment: Does the first step in this answer help? It looks similar to me https://stackoverflow.com/a/64472099/4964822

Comment: I will check it, it's similar, yes

Comment: @FedericoReggiani were you ever able to solve this? I'm sitting with the exact same issue...